# Does the Contents Section in Wordpress have any effect on SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, technical-seo

Some websites in Wordpress have Table of Contents in their articles. In this table of contents, there are H2 and H3 titles of the article. When you click on these titles, it goes to that title in the article.

Do you think this is important for SEO? Should I use it on my own website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main reasons for including a table of contents in technical books is to give people quick access to what they need and to help them understand the structural organisation of the content.

A similar principle applies to technical articles, both by readers and by Google. As you browse the web, you can observe that each article is unique. Therefore, it is important to consider when and how to use it according to the needs of your users and the structure of the content.

In short, when used in appropriate conditions, this type of content structure can be quite beneficial in terms of SEO.

Comment: You say yes, but don't really explain why... why does it improve user experience? Why then is there not a table of contents on every article and webpage?

Comment: @colinmcdermott In fact, it is up to the author whether it is in every article or not. You can put it if you want, but there is no need to include a table of contents in a single-titled article.

Comment: why though? without including the information in your answer it is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why technical books often have a table of contents at the start.

It allows people to jump straight to the section they need, and to understand the hierarchy of the content.

The same for technical articles, users, and Google.

You will note when browsing the web that not every article and not every webpage has one. Just like any web feature or technology, you need to decide when it is useful to your users and appropriate for your content.

So, yes, it is almost certainly a good thing for SEO if used in the right circumstances.